# C++ Function Returning Different Data Types

Tags: c++, template-function

First, allow me to apologize if the title of this question is vague.

That said, I'm trying to write a function that will return any one of a number of data types (all defined by me) based on conditions within the function. In essence, what I'm trying to do is this:

```
{
    A itemA;
    B itemB;
    C itemC;

    ...

    Do some calculations

    ...

    if (some condition)
        return itemA;
    else if (some other condition)
        return itemB;
    else
        return itemC;
}
```

Of course, this example is a little contrived but I think that gets my point across.

The classes A, B, and C are all child classes of some other class S but I don't want to return S as data will be lost if I do that. Further, the functionality doesn't really change even if the return type does so overloading it seems foolish. So then, should this be a template function or is there something else I need to do?

Thanks,

Comment: Declare `itemA`, `itemB` and `itemC` as pointers, allocate them dynamically, define function return type as `S*` (i.e., pointer to the base class). Welcome to world of polymorphism.

Comment: A function can only have one return type. What will be lost if `S` is the return type?

Comment: I hadn't thought of doing that but wouldn't I have to dynamic cast the result?

Comment: `itemA`, `itemB`, and `itemC` are local. So return by value can't be done. Second, `"the functionality doesn't really change even if the return type does so overloading it seems foolish"` -- so factor out the functionality that is the same and create a single function -- then call that function. I don't see what's "foolish" about that -- it is called `refactorization`.

Comment: This question has been asked sooo often... e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2237775 Search for "return different types [c++]" or something like that.

Comment: My apologies for the duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223777 answered it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you return a pointer or reference to `S`, you will not have a splicing problem:

```
S* func()
{ ... }
```

Note that you must dynamically allocate the variables.

Comment: That isn't going to work if A, B, and C are local variables, as shown by the OP's sample code.