# ASP.NET with MS Word

Tags: asp.net

All, I develop web pages in Visual Studio 2005 in Visual Basic. I want to create reports in MS Word (text and several Tables also). How can do it. Can u Help me

Comment: any reason for Word File? not Crystal reports  ?

Answer (score 4):

Don't use Office Automation on a server.  I don't know why so many there seem to be so many tutorials on using automation from ASP.NET when [Microsoft themselves recommend very strongly against it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

Don't go the HTML route either - it's a cheat, and while Word 2003 will happily open the files you send, Word 2007 will complain about the file extension being incorrect.

There's a [previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412/how-can-a-word-document-be-created-in-c) on creating Word documents using C#, and several of the answers/links apply to ASP.NET.  The two most common approaches are [WordML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164064.aspx) (XML - Word 2003) and [Office Open XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205.aspx) (Word 2007).

Comment: For Word 2007+ I use DocX from codeplex ;). It is working well and it's pretty much a no brainer.

Answer (score 1):

Aspose.Words is another great option.

http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx

Answer (score 0):

OfficeWriter is another third party tool specifically designed for scenarios like this:

http://www.officewriter.com