# Is there an expectable function to find out what type an image is in C# using OpenXML?

Tags: c#, image, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

I hooked into the question located at "[Replace image in word doc using OpenXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810138/replace-image-in-word-doc-using-openxml/2834047#2834047)". I noticed that there are several [ImagePartType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.imageparttype.aspx) types. Is there any easy "built in" way to determine which type a specific image should be other than going by it's extension? The ImagePartType enum is also used in PowerPoint as is alot of the WordProcessingML structures.,

For instance,
ImagePartType.Bmp on  image1.bmp
ImagePartType.Emf on  image1.emf
ImagePartType.Gif on  image1.gif
ImagePartType.Icon on  image1.ico
ImagePartType.Jpeg on  image1.jpeg or image1.jpg 
ImagePartType.Pcx on  image1.pcx
ImagePartType.Png on  image1.png
ImagePartType.Tiff on  image1.tiff or image1.tif
ImagePartType.Wmf on  image1.wmf

Comment: First off, welcome to stackoverflow! Secondly, why can't you go by file extension? If the data is named wrong, then you should alert the user in some fashion.

Comment: Actually no particular reason. I was mostly looking to see if there was a more "Official" way of doing things. And thanks for the warm welcome

Comment: Additionally, I'm grabbing items from an URL. It's part of an API. It's kinda hard to predict user content. I have a feeling that PowerPoint won't care too much, if worse comes to worse I can check mime type or something similar.

Comment: I haven't checked how/whether this is made available in the API, but the "correct" way should be to check the [Content_Types].xml part in the OpenXML package.

Comment: Tis over a year since I looked at this but decided it would be best to come back to it. Content_types don't have anything with the "Media" in there, so I ended up just checking the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not - because you can have filename.png which is actually a bmp file and it all works fine. The only way to know for sure is to read the actual bitmap file and see what format it is in.

You can do this either by loading it into an Image class, or just read the first couple of bytes and look for the signature of each of the formats.

Comment: so basically looking at the mime type. gotcha. Guess I could have checked into that.

Comment: Not the MIME type - that can be wrong too. You need to read the actual bitmap file. Most bitmap formats have a unique value for the first 2 bytes.