# How to get Image Name or Id from docx file using Open xml in C#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docx, openxml-sdk

I am using Mvc.Net API with open XML. I need to replace multiple images in .docx file.I replace the images in current scenario but I don't get any Id or Name of the Image at my code side so facing difficulties to replace those images.
Here is my code

```
List<ImagePart> imgPartList = doc.MainDocumentPart.ImageParts.ToList();
foreach(ImagePart imgPart in imgPartList)
            {
                string Id=doc.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(imgPart);
                byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(ImagePath);
                BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(imgPart.GetStream());
                writer.Write(imageBytes);
                writer.Close();
            }
```

Can I get the name of Image in ImagePart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
List<ImagePart> imgPartList = doc.MainDocumentPart.ImageParts.ToList();
           foreach(ImagePart imgPart in imgPartList)
                {
                    var imageId = document.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(imgPart.Id);
                    byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(ImagePath);
                    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(imgPart.GetStream());
                    writer.Write(imageBytes);
                    writer.Close();
                }
```

Also

[This answer could help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17947634/8289603)

Comment: Hi @Mr. R Thanks for your reply it helps me but my concern is The link you provided changed the images name I want the same image name for example if I added two images in docx User.jpg and UserId.jpg but at code side I got the image name like image1.jpg and image2.jpg instead of these changed name I want the original name so that I can replace the correct image, hope i am clear to you, Thanks in advance

Comment: I think open xml changed the actual image name in word doc, is this so?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't tell you exactly.

Comment: Thanks @Mr. R I achieved this goal thanks for share that link with your solution.