# Writing Text to Word document

Tags: asp.net, interface, ms-word

i need to create an application which writes text into a word document while typing on a TextBox.any one knows a interface to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a Word document be created in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412/how-can-a-word-document-be-created-in-c)

Comment: You can create the word file at server side and send it back to the client side.

Comment: Rob z has an excellent answer to this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412/how-can-a-word-document-be-created-in-c/10423#10423)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about creating and/or filling a Word document completely from code, I recommend that you take a look at the (commercial) [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) library.

If you are talking about "remote-controlling" Word from your own application, I recommend that you take a look at [Microsoft Office Automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384/en-us).