# Generate Word document from c#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can a Word document be created in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412/how-can-a-word-document-be-created-in-c)

In one of my application i need to generate the word document from the C# code. like we are using the sql as database and we are storing the inventory data from the c sharp code to sql database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are third-party libraries to help, but if you want to develop a solution yourself, you may want to get hold of [the Open XML SDK](http://openxmldeveloper.org/).

I recommend that rather than creating a Word document completely in code, you create a template document using Microsoft Word and then modify it using the Open XML SDK.

Don't be tempted to use Word Automation if you're producing the document on a server. Apart from being unsupported, it's somewhat prone to resource issues.

I [blogged](http://hastobe.net/blogs/stevemorgan/archive/2008/09/15/howto-insert-an-image-into-a-word-document-and-display-it-using-openxml.aspx) some time ago about inserting images into Word documents using Open XML.

Answer (score 1):

Hi please have a look into below link its realy good to understand the word automation.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx

http://vscontrols.blogspot.com/2010/09/genrate-table-of-files-in-directory.html

server side document genration

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735940(v=office.12).aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2009/01/19/pushing-data-from-a-database-into-a-word-document.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**How to automate Microsoft Word to create a new document by using Visual C#** 
 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384