# creating a word file by copying data from panel in c#

Tags: c#

HI

I have a panel in c# say panel2 which contains a few text boxes, buttons,labels and picture boxes. it also contains a data grid view with internal scroll property true.
I wish to take all these items from panel2 in a word file to be created on a simple button click event. I tried to write following code but it does not work.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\users\dell\desktop\temp.docx",panel2.select);
}
```

Comment: Do you want only the text box contents?
or a ScreenShot of the panel2?

Comment: What error did you get? More importantly, you cannot create a doc/docx file without specific library. It will work in .txt, but not a doc/docx.

Comment: @jacobaloysious: i want to copy all the contents. the screenshot will not work as the data grid view contains scroll bars.

Comment: @Fendy: The contents are not copied and the file is also not created.

Answer (score 1):

The .docx file is not a simple text file you can write to with File.WriteAllText. It is a very complex format (in fact it is a .zip file containing lots of xml files describing the structure and data of the document). Take a look at this question here: [Generate Word document from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802335/generate-word-document-from-c-sharp)

And also panel2.select won't do the job. You need to call textBox1.Text property in order to get the text from a TextBox. You will need to do that for everyone of them.