# Output bold text to doc file C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, streamwriter

I need to output text as bold to a doc file. I've looked into rtf markup and looked for an Office API, but I can't find anything. At the moment, I'm using HTML markup with `streamwriter` but I want something else, if possible.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: did you try Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word ??

Comment: @abhi The problem with that is that i need to handle multiple versions of word and my program will be using clickonce deployment so that will be a problem.

Comment: ok kurupt read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412/how-can-a-word-document-be-created-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help you on RTF format? http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/122443-bold-effect-in-rtf-file/

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this, hope this helps

[office with C#](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/creating-word-document-using-c/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have some budget, Spire.doc might be a solution for you: http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/word-for-net-introduce.html. They also support different Word doc formats.