# How to create doc 2003 file using C#

Tags: c#, itext, doc

Is there any way I can create doc file using C#. I have tried it but it does not open in 2003 but it opens in word 2007?

I have been using this code but the doc file does not open in word 2003:

```
//writing to doc file
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;               
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document oDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

oWord.Visible = false;

oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

//Insert a paragraph at the beginning of the document.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph oPara1;

oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
oPara1.Range.Text = text;

object fileName = "C:\\question.doc";
oDoc.SaveAs(ref fileName,
    ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
    ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
    ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
    ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
    ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

Comment: what version of Office are you using when executing this code ?

Comment: I'm using Word 2010 and visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `wdFormatDocument97` as the second parameter of `SaveAs()` - for details see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.saveas.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdsaveformat.aspx

EDIT - as per comment:

use

```
object vFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument97;
oDoc.SaveAs(ref fileName,
        ref vFormat, ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

Comment: Can you help how to write this in second parameter. It is giving me error?

Answer (score 1):

Refer this existing question:-

**[How can a Word document be created in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412/how-can-a-word-document-be-created-in-c)**

And other URLs for your reference:-

**[Walkthrough: Creating a Table in Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192483(v=office.11).aspx)**

**[Creating Word document using C#](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/creating-word-document-using-c/)**

Comment: I have tried all and by the way above code is taken from MSDN.