# Can StreamWriter/StreamReader write/read files other than .txt?

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

So I know how to use Streams in text files, but is there a way to use streams for files other than text? (I tried to use streams in a Word File, but it turned out to be corrupt.)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356903/how-to-write-text-into-a-word-file-using-c-net) for how you can write to Word files. `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` reads/writes _plain text_. Word files is not plain text.

Comment: That's because Word file - is binary file. Try to open it in Notepad++ for example, and you'll see that it is not readable.

Comment: MSWord `.docx` are a ZIPs having XMLs and other files: can be renamed and browsed, or opened as-is using a C# component. But old `.doc` are raw binaries and proprietary format. There is also for example `RTF` files, another format. What do you need?

Comment: .txt is a file extension, commonly used in conjunction with text files. If the file isn't a text file, then you'll have to use (or create something) that reads the file format you're dealing with according to it's specification.

Comment: "So I know how to use Streams in text files, but is there a way to use streams for files other than text?" - that sentence basically says "I have no idea what I'm doing with streams" - streams are *binary* pumps; it is TextReader/TextWriter that act as a bridge for text, and the specific TextReader/TextWriter that talk to streams are: StreamReader/StreamWriter. If you want to look at a binary file: Stream is fine - but that won't help you read a Word document, unless you also have a library that knows how to understand Word documents!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streams work with binary data. Your problem is most likely related to how you send data to the stream, not with the stream itself.

The `StreamWriter` class is specialized in converting strings to a binary data, and then sending them to a `Stream`.

If you want to write binary data to a stream, you can use the Stream interface itself. There's no need to use a Writer.